# generic Flux<T>.asFlow not available in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I need to convert a generic Flux (from reactor.core) to `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow`

I'm trying this code

```
    import kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.asFlow

    fun <T> genericFlux2FLow (flux: Flux<T>) {
     flux.asFlow()
    }
```

and the compiler says "Unresolved reference" for asFlow.

This code works though

```
  fun flux2Flow(flux: Flux<Int>) {
     flux.asFlow()
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `return`.  :) Ofc, you don't get flow object if you never return an object.

Comment: I think it it can't handle your possibly-nullable `T`, but what is the point of creating a function that simply calls another function that does exactly the same thing?

Comment: Did you remember to include the `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive` library as a dependency of your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your generic to `T : Any`

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> genericFlux2FLow(flux: Flux<T>): Flow<T> = flux.asFlow()
```

Comment: Wow it works, thanks! Now the question is... Why? :)

Comment: `a(): Type {...}` so `fun func() = a()` is equals `fun func(): Type { return a() }`

Comment: @MicheleDaRos this is because extension function `asFlow()` can only be applied to Publisher<T : Any> type (it means only to not-nullable types). But in your initial example, your T type can be nullable. That's why the compiler didn't recognize it.