# How to perform simple streaming queries using Spring R2DBC?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am looking for the equivalent of [`jdbcTemplate.queryForStream`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForStream(java.lang.String,org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter,org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper)) using R2DBC. I'm new to R2DBC, but this sounds like an ideal use case for it.

So far all I can find are examples of how to use spring-data-r2dbc for a JPA-like experience. This is really cool, but in my case this is overly complicated. I don't need any entity-mapping features or a persistence framework. I only need to perform simple, non-blocking queries. However, I can't find a single example of that in their docs or anything that even looks like it could be used for that purpose.

So, how can I perform basic queries with Spring + R2DBC? Bonus points if it integrates well with Kotlin coroutines like the [`CoroutineCrudRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/data/repository/kotlin/CoroutineCrudRepository.kt) does, though this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I found the way to do it, but I have not tested this code extensively yet. Implemented as an extension function on `r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient`

```kotlin
import io.r2dbc.spi.Row
import io.r2dbc.spi.RowMetadata
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.asFlow
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient

/**
 * Trying to mimic the behavior of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForStream
 */
fun <T : Any> DatabaseClient.queryForFlow(
    sqlTemplate: String,
    params: Map<String, Any>,
    rowMapper: (row: Row, metadata: RowMetadata) -> T,
): Flow<T> {

    val executionSpec = params.entries.fold(sql(sqlTemplate)) { executeSpec, (name, value) ->
        executeSpec.bind(name, value)
    }

    return executionSpec.map(rowMapper).all().asFlow()
}
```

Note the type variable is `T : Any` not just `T`, [otherwise you will not be able to use `asFlow()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234979/generic-fluxt-asflow-not-available-in-kotlin). You can omit this if you want to stay in the reactor framework and not use coroutines.

Trivial usage example:

```kotlin
class Example(private val dbClient: DatabaseClient) {
    
    fun getAllNames(id: Long): Flow<String> {
        
        val sqlTemplate = "SELECT name FROM foobar WHERE id=:id"
        val params = mapOf("id" to id)
        
        return dbClient.queryForFlow(sqlTemplate, params) {row, metadata -> 
            row.get(0, String::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```